# Asp.Net MVC how to create a Dashboard view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sidebar

I m trying to add a specific view to my Asp.net Mvc application, I mean a dashboard page. Thus I tried to add a side Bar menu with different items. What I need to do is to display a view that depends on the selected sidebar item in the same page.

Comment: I guess you can use a layout page which contains the bashboard items and once you click one of the items change the view. Or you can use single page...

Comment: I don't want the sidebar to be displayed at all pages, only when user try to display the dashboard

Comment: Oh, you mean its like a side panel (or something similiar) which can be hide or show by click on some button...am I right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to place your sidebar in `Layout.cshtml`

If you want to show **different items in sidebar**, you can check **current controller name and current controller action**

```
@if(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] == "Home")
{
   <li>item</li>
}
```

etc.

Another way is **create your own WebViewPage** and have your custom variables available in your Views. It could be controller name, action name or whatever else.

Another less recommended way is save preferred sidebar name in ViewBag. It means in your `Page.cshtml` will contains:

```
@{
   ViewBag.PreferredSidebar = "default";
}
```

and later you can work with this value in `Layout.cshtml`:

```
@if(ViewBag.PreferredSidebar  == "default")
{
   @Html.Partial("SidebarDefault")
}
```

You can combine this ways.

If you want to **user can hide/show sidebar clicking on some button** a remember this settings, you can use for example **JavaScript** and **HTML5 Local Storage** (settings will be stored for current user and his browser).